# How to mirror a GitHub repo using Github actions?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I would like to know if there is a way to use GitHub Actions to automatically mirror changes from `repoA` to `repoB`.

Both would be private repositories.
The workflow would be like this: a commit would be pushed to a branch on `repoA` and then automatically the same commit would be sent to `repoB` as well.

I've seen posts on adding a remote repository, but would be interested to see how GitHub Actions can help to improve this.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible. However, why do you wanna do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might consider a GitHub Action like [Git Sync](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/git-sync-action):

> A GitHub Action for syncing between two independent repositories using force push.

You add use in it an SSH private key to access to your second repository

```
ssh_private_key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
```

(since you can [create and store encrypted secrets](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets) in a workflow)